# 403 Forbidden NGINX phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, debian

Салют всем! Есть ноут, на нем Debian 8 + Nginx

Запускаю локально phpmyadmin
http://pma.test/ - всё ок!
http://test/pma/ - 403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.2

Вопрос: в чем ошибка и как её устранить?

Конфиг nginx для сайта

```
server{
    server_name test;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;
    root /home/miha/opt/test/www;

    location ~ \\.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;    
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /
    {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }    

location /pma/ {
alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
index index.php;
location ~ \\.php$ {
fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
} 
}
    location /errors {
         alias /home/www-data/mysite/errors ;
    }
    error_page 404 /errors/404.html;        
}

server {
server_name pma.test;
access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;


location /
{
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
}

location ~ \\.php$
{
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;

}
}
```

В access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2016:00:14:59 +0300] "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1" 403 142 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

В error.log

```
2016/07/17 00:14:59 [error] 2271#0: *14 directory index of "/usr/share/phpmyadmin" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: test, request: "GET /pma/ HTTP/1.1", host: "test"
```

Права на папки сайта и /usr/share/phpmyadmin 777

Comment: вероятно, в `location /pma/` не хватает указания `index index.php`. // а вообще странно, как у вас `\\ ` в location срабатывает.

Comment: index index.php; - добавил, перезагрузил, в вопросе изменил сожержимое. По прежнему 403. В логах ошибки те же

Comment: А почему у вас root /home/miha/opt/test/www; вместо root /usr/share/phpmyadmin ? У вас где сами php-файлы phpMyAdmin расположены?

Comment: @cheops Сами файлы в /usr/share/phpmyadmin расположены. Если я root добавляю под location /pma/ { после alias = ошибка nginx не перезапускается. А выше root прописан я так думаю для того чтобы по адресу http://test были файлы сайта, а по адресу http://test/pma/ - phpmyadmin... Или я загнул?

Comment: если я в самом верху в блоке server указываю root /usr/... то по адресу http://test начинает работать phpmyadmin, а по http://test/pma/ по прежнему 403.